# How to tell if a transaction is related to an NFT (erc721) transaction or not in etherscan

Tags: ethereum, etherscan

How can we say if the following transaction is related to NFT (ERC721) transaction or not in Etherscan?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe2be6b09de94d1e17e575141adfa4351d97fa1ca1a619a3397403c51db0fa6a1

Answer (score 2):

The [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) standard defines `Transfer` event that has to be emitted with each token transfer, containing 3 topics:

- 1st `indexed` topic is the sender address
- 2nd `indexed` topic is the recipient address
- 3rd `indexed` topic is the token ID

The [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard defines a very similar `Transfer` event, also with 3 topics. But the 3rd topic, representing the amount of transferred tokens, is **not indexed**.

So when you look at the [event logs](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe2be6b09de94d1e17e575141adfa4351d97fa1ca1a619a3397403c51db0fa6a1#eventlog) produced by this transaction, there are two `Transfer` events. Both of them have the 3rd topic non-indexed, meaning they are transferring ERC-20 tokens - not NFTs. If they were transferring NFTs, the 3rd topic would be `indexed`.

Comment: Is there a way to detect this given the contract address? I have a contract address and I just want to check if it's erc721 or erc20

Comment: @Byrd Yes - address of the contract that emitted the event log is stored in the `address` property of the event log object.

Comment: Although I'd like it to be this simple, this may not always be the case, ERC721 contracts like cryptokitties (0x06012c8cf97BEaD5deAe237070F9587f8E7A266d) and cryptopunks (0xb47e3cd837dDF8e4c57F05d70Ab865de6e193BBB) both have non-indexed tokenId parameter.

Comment: @SupratikChaudhuri These specific contracts do not implement the ERC721 standard (even though they are widely recognized NFT collections). The answer focuses on the standardized implementation of the event.